# TortoiseSVN Add user & reset password

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

So I've searched through the forums and google isn't helping right now so hopefully someone can help me with this.

I have a new user. He needs to be able to access TortoiseSVN (the repository). It prompts him for a username and password which I do not know where to setup at. Does anyone know how to create a new user and reset a password so he can access the repository?
TortoiseSVN 1.14.5,
Subversion 1.14.2

Comment: TortoiseSVN is a client program, not a server. You have to find out out how to add a new account **on your server**. So where is your server installed? Are you an admin of that server? If not, contact an admin for assistance.

Comment: Pretty much. I'm not sure how to add a new account on the server, let a lone really access it

Comment: if you are using VisualSVN Server, then you can add and manage user accounts via the VisualSVN Server Manager console on the server computer. If you are using some other server distribution, then most likely it has an admin's web panel that lets you manage user accounts. If you have a self-built SVN server, then search for the `htpasswd` file that should have the list of user accounts (account name and password hash).

Comment: Thank you for the above comment. Part of the overall problem is that our Admin kind of left us high and dry and didn't tell anyone anything about subversion, let alone any admin tools. So half the battle is finding everything

Comment: So I figured out how to add/manage users for SVN.  Solution for me is as follows: I had to access or navigate to the server via the file explorer. Theres a folder titled [Repositories]. From here, I chose the correct repository that I needed to add the user to. From there, go to the config folder. There are two files that you want to edit. They are the authz file and the passwd file. You can add users and assign them passwords from here. Once I updated this file, I needed to remote into our server (that SVN is on) and go into Services and restart my subversion service. This worked for me